# SQL Left Join Conditions

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, join

Hello Everyone and Anyone,

I have an issue I was hoping to resolve using a Left Join using conditions, however, I have yet to figure it out and I'm beginning to get a headache. I am looking to pull data in using a left join however I only want two columns to be included and I want the condition to be based on a 3rd column from this second table. Also I am open to solutions that don't necessarily require a left join condition.

```
Select a.ID,
a.AssociateName,
a.FormTypeID
b.Segment1
b.Segment2
From NinjaTable a
Left Join ShinobiTable b On b.AssociateName = a.AssociateName
```

Here is the condition that I need (I am going to word it in an if statement although i know it does not apply) What makes this tricky is it is possible for the associate to have more than 1 assignment Status. They may have moved to another department and their previous listing now shows inactive however they still have another active one. I need the condition to essentially grab the Active one only if applicable else if there is not an Active one then grab the inactive one

```
IF b.AssignmentStatus = 'Active' then perform left join Normally
IF b.AssignmentStatus = 'Inactive' Then only perform left join if there is not an active one.
```

Comment: It may not be strictly neccesary, but the table definitions may help.  A left join will get you all the data in the left table and any matching data or null in the second table.  Is this what you want?

Comment: how about two subqueries filtered by `WHERE`, then `UNION`'d together?

Comment: Some sample data and expected results are always helpful :]

Comment: Are you using both MySQL and MS SQL Server? (Don't tag products not involved...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can include both status records and then coalesce them, e.g:

```
Select a.ID,
a.AssociateName,
a.FormTypeID,
coalesce(b.Segment1, c.Segment1),
coalesce(b.Segment2, c.Segment2)
From NinjaTable a
Left Join ShinobiTable b On b.AssociateName = a.AssociateName and b.AssignmentStatus = 'Active'
Left Join ShinobiTable c On c.AssociateName = a.AssociateName and c.AssignmentStatus = 'Inactive'
```

Comment: You are Awesome Gordy! this is exactly what I needed! I do have a slight problem, however, its not from what you provided more or less i am still getting 4 duplicates. Because (And i just found this out) there is going to be an occasion where an associate moves departments more than once in the roster. so i have a couple associates who have 1 Active Record and 2 Inactive Records and thus in the second left join its creating a duplicate record for the second inactive. I will say that it does show only the correct segment data but its a dupe :(